# From dataframe to a nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, nested

I am experiencing some hard time trying in creating a nested dictionary from a dataframe in python and would really appreciate your help.This is what the data looks like.

|  | tag | id | cat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | PA14_00030 | GO:0005524 | F |
| 1 | PA14_00030 | GO:0006281 | P |
| 2 | PA14_00050 | GO:0003677 | F |
| 3 | PA14_00050 | GO:0003918 | F |
| 4 | PA14_00050 | GO:0005524 | F |
| 5 | PA14_00050 | GO:0006265 | P |
| 6 | PA14_00060 | GO:0016746 | F |
| 7 | PA14_00070 | GO:0005975 | C |
| 8 | PA14_00080 | GO:0009055 | C |

I want to create a nested dictionary that will look something like this:

```
{'C':{'PA14_00080':{'GO:0009055'},'PA14_00070':{'GO:0005975'}},
'F':{'PA14_0003': {'GO:0005524'}, 'PA14_00050': {'GO:0003677', 'GO:0003918','GO:0005524'}}, 
'P':{PA14_00050:{GO:0006265}, PA14_00030:{GO:0006281}}}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can do:

```py
out = {
    k: {
        row["tag"]: set(g.loc[g["tag"] == row["tag"], "id"].to_list())
        for _, row in g.iterrows()
    }
    for k, g in df.groupby("cat")
}

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "C": {"PA14_00070": {"GO:0005975"}, "PA14_00080": {"GO:0009055"}},
    "F": {
        "PA14_00030": {"GO:0005524"},
        "PA14_00050": {"GO:0003918", "GO:0005524", "GO:0003677"},
        "PA14_00060": {"GO:0016746"},
    },
    "P": {"PA14_00030": {"GO:0006281"}, "PA14_00050": {"GO:0006265"}},
}
```